# How to create popup boxes next to the links when mouse over them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is what I want to implement:

I have two hyperlinks that are displayed on the webpage:

```
<a href="http://foo.com"> foo </a>

<a href="http://bar.com"> bar </a>
```

and I also have two descriptions to the links as divs:

```
<div id="foo">foo means foo</div>

<div id="bar">bar means bar</div>
```

Now, when I mouse over the link of foo, the corresponding description div should pop up, and it should pop up right next to where my cursor is.

So if I mouse over "foo", a pop-up box containing "foo means foo" should appear right next to the mouse cursor. Same thing applies to "bar".

Please show a quick and simple way to implement this, with javascript/jquery, CSS, or combination of these.

P.S. I apologize for didn't explain clearly earlier, I actually want to add further links or images into the description div instead of pure text so a regular tool-tip perhaps would not do.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use one of the many tooltip plugins out there?

Comment: I apologize for didn't explain clearly, I actually want to add further links or images into the description div instead of pure text. So I thought the regular tooltip would not do.

Comment: I think [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) could be interesting for your needs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the simpliest solution.

*HTML:*

```
<a href="http://foo.com" data-tooltip="#foo">foo</a>
<a href="http://bar.com" data-tooltip="#bar">bar</a>

<div id="foo">foo means foo</div>
<div id="bar">bar means bar</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    ...
}​
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$("a").hover(function(e) {
    $($(this).data("tooltip")).css({
        left: e.pageX + 1,
        top: e.pageY + 1
    }).stop().show(100);
}, function() {
    $($(this).data("tooltip")).hide();
});
```

```js
$("a").hover(function(e) {
  $($(this).data("tooltip")).css({
    left: e.pageX + 1,
    top: e.pageY + 1
  }).stop().show(100);
}, function() {
  $($(this).data("tooltip")).hide();
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding:5px 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: lavender;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://foo.com" data-tooltip="#foo">foo</a>
<a href="http://bar.com" data-tooltip="#bar">bar</a>

<div id="foo">foo means foo</div>
<div id="bar">bar means bar</div>
```

**​DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8UkHn/

Comment: Super~ Exactly what I was looking for, simple, clean and no 3rd party plug-ins.. worked like a charm, thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered using a "title" attribute in this case?

```
<a href="http://foo.com" title="foo means foo"> foo </a>
```

See if this fits your need.

What it does is, when you move mouse over the link "foo", a small box containing "foo means foo" will appear next to the mouse pointer.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually want to add further links or images into the description div instead of pure text. sorry didn't explain it clearly