# jQuery: description box won't display - why?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to make 2 links that show a description box on mouseover. Said description box is to hide on mouseout. The requirement I got is to do it with Javascript or jQuery (no other 3rd party plugins or similar). So far so good.

I'm not good at all at either Javascript or jQuery, so Google took me to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586962/how-to-create-popup-boxes-next-to-the-links-when-mouse-over-them), where I found [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8UkHn/). This is exactly what I was looking for. When I changed the code with what I want to display, the links are shown but not the description boxes.

If I modify the JSFiddle and run it with the texts I wanna show, the whole thing works, but it doesn't work on my browsers. I have tried in PC and Mac, IE11 and FF 40.0.3. I tried also without the script link that links to the jQuery library file and it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
   <title>Project 1: description boxes on links</title>
   <style>
    div {
       position: absolute;
       display: none;
       background: #ccc;
       border: 1px solid;
    }

   </style>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $("a").hover(function(e) {
            $($(this).data("tooltip")).css({
                left: e.pageX + 1,
            top: e.pageY + 1
            }).stop().show(100);
    }, function() {
            $($(this).data("tooltip")).hide();
    });


   </script> 
</head>

<body>
   <a href="http://pagea.com" data-tooltip="#pageA">My link 1</a>
   <br><br>
   <a href="http://pageb.com" data-tooltip="#pageB">My link 2</a>

   <div id="pageA">This links goes to page A</div>
   <div id="pageB">This link goes to page B</div>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wrap your code in document-ready handler or move your script to end of page

Comment: take a look at this code for [reference](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a document loads, the script is run as soon as it is reached in the document. This means that the rest of the DOM has probably not loaded before your script gets called. You can get round this by wrapping your script in a jQuery event listener, like so:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("a").hover(function(e) {
            $($(this).data("tooltip")).css({
                left: e.pageX + 1,
            top: e.pageY + 1
            }).stop().show(100);
        }, function() {
            $($(this).data("tooltip")).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Another way is to put your script at the button of the document just before the closing `</body>` element.